# Cabal install reports package as installed, but Setup configure reports it as missing

Tags: haskell, cabal-install

I am using `ghc-7.6.3` with `cabal-install` version `1.18.0.5` using version `1.18.1.3` of the `Cabal` library. My operating system is Debian Wheezy 7.5.
I have a fresh cabal install, and that I have removed the `.ghc` from my home directory.
After that I have changed the `cabal` `config` file and set:

```
remote-repo: stackage-nightly-2014-12-15:http://www.stackage.org/snapshot/nightly-2014-12-15
```

After that I did (following [this documentation](http://www.yesodweb.com/page/quickstart))

```
$ cabal update
$ cabal install alex happy yesod-bin
```

and the build complained that it cannot build package `system-filepath-0.4.12`.

So, I am trying to build package `system-filepath-0.4.12` manually. After unpacking the archive, I `cd`-ed to the unpacked folder and entered:

```
$ ghc -o Setup Setup.hs
$ ./Setup configure
```

which gives:

```
Configuring system-filepath-0.4.12...
Setup: At least the following dependencies are missing:
text >=0.7.1
```

But

```
$ cabal install text
```

gives:

```
Resolving dependencies...
All the requested packages are already installed:
text-1.1.1.3
Use --reinstall if you want to reinstall anyway.
```

How is it possible that a package is reported as installed and missing at the same time?
Should I look for a more stable `remote-repo` configuration, is there something I can check that might fix the missing `text` package? Note that I am not using a sandbox.

**EDIT**

Thanks for pointing out that there are two package databases.
I have now tried both

```
$ cabal configure
$ cabal build
```

and

```
$ Setup configure --user
$ Setup build
```

Both give no error during configuration, but give the following error during the build phase:

```
Building system-filepath-0.4.12...
Preprocessing library system-filepath-0.4.12...
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lHStext-1.1.1.3-ghc7.8.3
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Are you using sandboxes? If so remove the sandbox and try again. If not then use a sandbox.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead

```
cd system-filepath--0.4.12
cabal configure
```

I am not sure why, but this works for me, whereas Setup.hs gave me the same error (truth be told, I always do it the `cabal configure` way, and am not sure if your way should also work).

Answer (score 1):

There are (at least) two package databases: a global one available to all users, and a user-specific one. By default, `Setup.hs` looks in (and installs to) the global one, and cabal-install looks in (and installs to) the user-specific one. You can manually choose one or the other with `--user` and `--global`; so, you could fix this either by using

```
./Setup configure --user
```

or by

```
cabal install text --global
```

You can see the current state of the package databases with `ghc-pkg`, which will report information about both by default.